# Ignite cache TreeMap

Tags: ignite, treemap

When I create an Apache Ignite cache I believe it is implemented as a HashMap

Is it possible to configure it as a TreeMap, so that the order of the keys is guaranteed?

Comment: What's the goal of storing the keys in such an order? Ignite ScanQueries can iterate through data efficiently and SQL can be used for advanced data access.

Comment: However, Ignite implements indexing for SQL queries, so I assume it would have some value for scan queries.

Comment: Also, the restriction to SQL 99 is a problem, particularly with respect to UPDATE without a FROM clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible since at different times keys may belong on different nodes so iteration order will depend on cluster topology.

If cache in question is small, you can use `ORDER BY _key` together with SQL.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought this might be so but it's good to have it confirmed.